# Email confirmation in user registration form without a plugin

Tags: user-registration, email-verification

I have created an HTML registration form for users in a custom template. Now I want to send an email confirmation link in registered emails from which registered users can login.

Below is my code. Registration is successfully done. How can I generate the confirmation link?

```
if($_POST){
     $username= $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtusername']);
     $email= $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtEmail']);
    $password= $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtpassword']);
     $confpassword= $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtconfirmpassword']);

     $error=array();

     if(strpos($username,' ')!==FALSE){
       $error['username_space']="username has space";

     }

     if(empty($username)){
         $error['username_empty']="username needed";
     }
     if(username_exists($username)){
     $error['username_exist']="username already exists";

     }

  if(!is_email($email)){
      $error['email_valid']="enter valid email id";

     }

     if(email_exists($email)){
      $error['email_existence']="email already exists";

     }

     if(strcmp($password, $confpassword)){
      $error['password']="password doesnt match";

     }

     if(count($error)==0) {
      wp_create_user($username,$password,$email);
      echo "you have registered succesfully.. ";

    $new_user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    wp_new_user_notification($username,$password,$email);
    exit();
     }

     else{
        print_r($error);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the arguments you are passing for the `wp_new_user_notification()` function are incorrect - it requires the user ID, not the username. Also, that may not be what you want to use in this case since it generates a link that will require the user to set a password (which is preferred).

I'll go through two examples - one without the password, which the user would then set upon confirmation; and one with the password, which would require using a custom email instead of `wp_new_user_notification()`.

**Preferred Method (no password)**

This assumes you'll take out the password fields in your form and allow the user to set their password when they return via the link included in the new user notification email.  Other issues are discussed after the code:

```
if($_POST){
     $username= sanitize_user($_POST['txtusername']);
     $email= sanitize_email($_POST['txtEmail']);

     $error=array();

     if(strpos($username,' ')!==FALSE){
       $error['username_space']="username has space";

     }

     if(empty($username)){
         $error['username_empty']="username needed";
     }
     if(username_exists($username)){
     $error['username_exist']="username already exists";

     }

  if(!is_email($email)){
      $error['email_valid']="enter valid email id";

     }

     if(email_exists($email)){
      $error['email_existence']="email already exists";

     }

     if(count($error)==0) {
      $user_id = wp_create_user($username,$password,$email);
      echo "you have registered succesfully.. ";

    wp_new_user_notification($user_id);
    exit();
     }

     else{
        print_r($error);
        }
}
```

Important changes here to note:

1. The escape method you were using is specifically for the WPDB object. Instead, when handling posted form data, you want to sanitize.  There are appropriate WP functions for this, including the two I changed in your function - [`sanitize_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/) and [`sanitize_email()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/).
2. You're using [`wp_create_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/) and then immediately using [`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/).  Unless you have code outside of this snippet that is assembling the `$userdata` value you have in that function, **this is unnecessary**.  `wp_create_user()` actually runs `wp_insert_user()` and then returns the user ID.  So I removed that unnecessary function (since the data it was passing was an undefined variable in your code anyway).
3. The arguments you're passing to [`wp_new_user_notification()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/) are **incorrect**. The function accepts two arguments separated by a deprecated argument that no longer is used.  So it's `$user_id` (not username), the empty deprecated argument (empty since it's ignored), then the optional `$notify` (empty, user, admin, or both) - `wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, '', '')`. The `$user_id` value comes from `wp_create_user()`. The second two arguments I left off since the one is ignored by the function, and the other is optional (if not set, it will just send to the user).

Note carefully, #3 above, because what you were sending to that function is probably why you were having trouble with it. First, you were passing the user's username instead of the user ID, so the function would never find the user.  But more importantly, if you look at the actual function, if the third argument is anything other than 'user', 'admin' , 'both' or default '', the function quits right there. You were passing the user's email in this position, so the function would quit right away.

I've linked the documentation for these functions - it's a good idea to review that information when you're using WP core functions to make sure you're using them correctly.

**Alternate method:**

Here's the alternate method I promised. This corrects similar issues, such as only using `wp_create_user()`. But the difference is that you'll need to create and send your own customized email, since the `wp_new_user_notification()` function assumes you're sending a link for the user to set their password (which you're already collecting in your form).

In order to send your custom email, it uses [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) (which, like the above code, you should take some time to review the function's documentation so you know what it does and how to use it).

```
if($_POST){
     $username= sanitize_user($_POST['txtusername']);
     $email= sanitize_email($_POST['txtEmail']);
    $password= $_POST['txtpassword'];
     $confpassword= $_POST['txtconfirmpassword']);

     $error=array();

     if(strpos($username,' ')!==FALSE){
       $error['username_space']="username has space";

     }

     if(empty($username)){
         $error['username_empty']="username needed";
     }
     if(username_exists($username)){
     $error['username_exist']="username already exists";

     }

  if(!is_email($email)){
      $error['email_valid']="enter valid email id";

     }

     if(email_exists($email)){
      $error['email_existence']="email already exists";

     }

     if(strcmp($password, $confpassword)){
      $error['password']="password doesnt match";

     }

     if(count($error)==0) {
      $user_id = wp_create_user($username,$password,$email);
      echo "you have registered succesfully.. ";

        $subject = 'Thanks for registering';
        $message = 'Thanks for registering. 

            Please return to the site to log in:

            https://example.com/my-login/';

        wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message );

        exit();
     }

     else{
        print_r($error);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!. your explanation was accurate and helped me alot :) . can you help me with verification link code. right now ,after signup , i am getting message" you have succesfully registered". as i am implemeneting email verification first time. i dont have much idea. please help.

Comment: my verification is working now. thanks for your effort!! .

Comment: Glad to hear things are working for you!